# Why do default values overwrite values that have been set through an overridden method

Tags: java

Setting a variable which has a default value, like `public boolean test = false;` from the example, through an overridden method causes it to be set to the default value once it gets to the constructor. If I, however, change it to `public boolean test;` it works just as I expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* False */
    System.out.println(new Test2().test);
}

public static class Test {

    public Test() {
        this.test();

        /* True */
        System.out.println(((Test2) this).test);
    }

    public void test() {}

    public static class Test2 extends Test {

        public boolean test = false;

        public Test2() {
            /* False */
            System.out.println(this.test);
        }

        @Override
        public void test() {
            this.test = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering what causes this behaviour and if there is anything you can do to prevent it, other than not having a default value?

Comment: Don't invoke overridden methods from a superclass constructor. That's what's causing the problem.

Comment: What is the full output you're expecting and why?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, constructor of base class with no argument gets automatically called in derived class constructor.

In your case, when you create an instance of Test2 class, Java first call the constructor of the base class (the no argument constructor of Test), which call the override test() method from the derived class.

Initializer of the field test to value false is processed during construction just before any other logic in your constructor, but after calling the base class constructor.

Find below the order of execution of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Test2().test); // 6 - print false
}

public static class Test {

    public Test() {
        this.test(); // 1 - call the test method from derivative class

        System.out.println(((Test2) this).test); // 3 - print true
    }

    public void test() {}

    public static class Test2 extends Test {

        public boolean test = false; // 4 - set the test field to false

        public Test2() {
            System.out.println(this.test); // 5 - print false
        }

        @Override
        public void test() {
            this.test = true; // 2 - set the test field to true
        }
    }
}
```